# Error in loading data using DB2 load command in DB2 10.5

Tags: performance, db2, java, db2-9.5, db2-10.5

I have a IBM DB2 database in our application. We have a monthly Java batch process which loads data in the tables using

"load Replace"
sql command. Around millions of record will be updated every month in this batch process.
The batch was running fine without any issues in the DB2 version 9.5 . Recently the database was updated to DB2 Version V10.5. After the upgrade , we face the following issues in the batch process. (No change in the code)

There is an Interrupted Exception occurring in the middle of the process.
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-952, SQLSTATE=57014, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.69.24

The data in which the data gets loaded is also getting slow after some time. At first the data ets loaded in around 50,000 rows /sec. After some time it is getting loaded at the rate of 1000 rows/second.

TheCPU utilization is also getting increased gradually as the load starts.

We select data from the input tables using Java JDBC connection.Then we process the data and store the data in temporary files. From the files we insert data in the utput tables using the load command. Is there any upgrade issue or enhancement in DB2 10.5, that does not support this. Will using cursor solve this issue. I am also not sure if there is any connection problems in the new version of Db2.
Any help is highly appreciated. Please comment for any additional information required.

Comment: Cross-posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34680250/error-in-loading-data-using-db2-load-command-in-db2-10-5

Comment: What is the full sql statement? Minus sensitive stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run runstats recently for at least the relevant tables and indexes?
Are you sure you have index(es) to support your monthly batch?
Have you checked the bufferpool hit ratio when the batch is running?
db2top and db2advis may help you answering these questions.

The secret optimizer was surely changed and it may see tiny details differently than the previous version, that can cause dramatic differences. It's always a good idea to pamper it with runstats when unexplainable slowdown is seen and check the rest when there is no benefit.